# ¿Como puedo sumar valores traídos de firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter

soy nuevo en flutter y quiera saber si puede ayudarme. Estoy recuperando unos valores int de Firestore y necesito sumarlos. Entiendo que se puede con un bucle for pero hasta el momento no encuentro como hacerlo. espero puedan ayudarme.

[image: Codigo]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes! Una sugerencia: procura siempre compartir tu código como texto para que otros puedan revisarlo y probarlo más fácil (la respuesta tampoco será una imagen!). Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0):

Asumiré que dentro de cada documento el valor `int` que deseas sumar se llama `numero`, ya que no lo especificaste.

```
var sumaTotal=0;
snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc){sumaTotal=sumaTotal+doc.data()['numero'];})
```

luego de esto tendrás la suma de los valores en el campo `número` por cada documento recorrido.

otra forma sería con `for in`

```
  for(final doc in snapshot.data.documents){
     sumaTotal=sumaTotal+doc.data()['numero'];
  }
```